# Setting loading icon for Chromecast

Tags: android, google-cast

How to set app logo for loading Chromecast? When I cast some media I see app logo like a splash screen (Youtube for example). I want to set my logo and title for my app but cannot find in docs how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Default Media Receiver, then you cannot customize that. If you are using the Styled Media Receiver, then you can modify the .splash class in your own CSS.

If you are using a custom CAF receiver, then you can update your CSS to show a splash screen when the receiver is loaded:

```
  <cast-media-player id="player"></cast-media-player>
  <style>
    #player {
        --theme-hue: 210;
        --splash-image: url("my.png");
    }
```